# How to bind large amount of images wpf c# from url?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox

I have a view where I have a Listbox. A try to fill it with about 5000 images from url-s. I have the list of the images, but when I try to bind it I have to wait a lots of time before i see the images. It display images very slowly.

```
public static FileDto MapToFileDto(this FileUploadedResponzeJsonDto resp)
{
    var dto = new FileDto();

    dto.Delete_url = resp.Delete_url;
    dto.File_ID = resp.File_ID;
    dto.FileName = resp.Name;
    dto.FileSizeInBytes = resp.FileSizeInBytes;
    dto.Info_url = resp.Info_url;
    dto.Url = resp.Url;
    dto.Visits = resp.Visits;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.Surl) && resp.Name.HasImageExtension())
    dto.DisplayImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format(ClientConstans.API_URL_GET_SMALL_IMAGE, resp.Surl)));

    return dto;
}
```

This makes the url-s like this:

```
string.Format(ClientConstans.API_URL_GET_SMALL_IMAGE, resp.Surl)
// https://mysite/image.png
```

I fill a list with FileDto and bind it to the Listbox. It creates the list quick, but then I have to wait a lot for the images.

How should I fill the listbox with the images if I want to show them in no time?
(they are really small images, about 4kb/image)

And another problem I have that I can't broke the connection. When I clear the list and try to refill I can't do it. It throws me just an exception, becouse the URI bindings.

Comment: Try loading the image on the background thread and download the images simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void LoadImageAsync(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var senderItem = sender as Image;

    if (senderItem != null)
    {
        var dataContext = senderItem.DataContext as FileDto;
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataContext.ImageUrl))
            {
                var fullFilePath = dataContext.ImageUrl;

                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(fullFilePath, UriKind.Absolute);
                bitmap.EndInit();

                senderItem.Source = bitmap;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I load images on the image control's Loaded event async. Its's very quick and use only a little memory and processor.

Comment: It is the sender item. I mage a bitmap image and pass it to the sender image control's source. .. oh you mean var image = new... ? That's not needed, it was a try, sorry its my bad. :)